# Retrieving only the word from the source via switch/case

Tags: switch-statement, pentaho, kettle, pdi

with the reference to sample data in PDI

> `C:\pdi-ce-5.2.0.0-209\data-integration\samples\transformations\Switch-Case - substring example.ktr` 
>   the output of this .ktr is such that it sends data across the step matching the string. But what if I want to forward the string that is been mentioned and not the entire line containing the string. for e.g the Case value mentioned in switch is 
>   [image] 
>   and the target step mentioned is in dummy step with as world,hello,others(for defaults)

[image]

the output(in dummy step) shows the occurrence of the word that was specified,but here I just want only the word the we mention in case value.
I tried inserting space after the word world and hello but it didn't worked.seeking help for the same.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The match has different output steps, so you could add the constant after the match.

Comment: I want to extract only the match string and not the whole line containing the word, is this possible using Switch/case

Comment: No, but you know the match string, so you can add it manually.

Comment: alright I would surely try this stuff..Thanks @bolav

Comment: No. You need to use the regex step - that supports capture groups and you can then get only the "matching" part of the string.